# List of designated terrorist organizations & their tendency of faith

Tags: terrorism, religion

I read this page on wikipedia: [List of designated terrorist organizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations)

We can't say that this page is 100% trustable, however I couldn't find a better source (better definition also questionable itself for this topic.)

What this page says me Muslim groups are dominating the list.

The countries whose people have islamophobia perception are fair to have this perception depending on this page.

Note: Oxford definition for this term:

*Islamophobia: A hatred or fear of Islam or Muslims, especially as a political force.*

I am a Muslim too. And it makes me sad that there are some very bloody groups which call themselves Muslims and try to explain the reasons of their acts by means of faith issues. This creates islamphobia and/or empowers the perception of.

I am an engineer and believe the power of scientific approach of root cause.

I am not sure if this question can be a scientific question (anyway, I wonder your valuable thoughts) however I want to ask that *why (main branches at least) groups who call themselves Muslim & try to explain the reasons of their acts by means of Islamic issues dominate the list of 'designated terrorist organizations'*?

Comment: There are terrorist organizations like the Animal Liberation Front, which are secular I think (or maybe they are witches and worship the Earth). How do you want to count secular terrorist groups?

Answer (score 3):

I think the main reason is that groups in the Middle East (and other places with a dominantly Muslim population) define their group in religious terms while groups in other places generally define their group in secular terms.